# What is the time complexity of deleting a node in a binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, big-o, time-complexity

For  deleting a node in the binary tree, we have to search the node. That is possible in minimum O(log N) and max O(N). Depending on the node, we have to rearrange the pointers. How do we calculate the time complexity of that.

Answer (score 14):

That depends on how you're doing the deletion.  The most common way involves finding the successor of the node, then replacing the node with that successor.  This can be done in O(h), where h is the height of the tree.  In the worst case this is O(n), but in a balanced tree is worst-case O(lg n).

Answer (score 3):

Yes best case complexity is O(logn) (when perfectly balanced) and 
worst case complexity is O(n) 
 1 - 2 - 3 - 4

But  **the main problem**  with BST deletion (Hibbard Deletion) is that It is not symmetric. After many insertion and deletion BST become less balance. Researchers proved that after sufficiently long number of random insert and delete height of the tree becomes  **sqrt(n)** . so now every operation (search, insert, delete) will take  **sqrt(n)**  time which is not good compare to  **O(logn)** .

This is very long standing(around 50 years) open problem to efficient symmetric delete for BST. for guaranteed balanced tree, we have to use RedBlack Tree etc.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting the "worst search time as max O(N)"?  That should never happen in a BST.  At worst, it should be max O(h) for search and delete, where 'h' is the height of the tree.  See this [helpful article](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~siff/CS367/Notes/bsts.html).

Comment: O(h) can be O(n) in a pathologically degenerate tree.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the complexity is searching for the node.  Once it has been found—as long as the parent node is retained—it is only a few more assignments to delete the node. So it is a constant order.

Answer (score 0):

In case of deletion, there are two factors which affects the cost of deletion of node:

1. Locating the parent node of target node / traversing till the parent node of the target node:

This might so happen that the pointer to the target node is given but the pointer to parent node of target node is not given, keep in mind that it is the parent node which will (after the deletion of target node) have to point to the in-order successor or predecessor of the target node. Hence, if the pointer to parent node is not given you will have to traverse till you find the parent node of target node.

The **best** case to find the parent node of target node is **O(log n)** for a balanced tree.

The **worst** case to find the parent node of target node is **O(n)** for a skewed tree.

2. The adjustment or rearrangement of tree after deletion of target node:

During the adjustment, the cost involved in finding the in-order predecessor or successor of the target node is taken in account, since after finding the in-order predecessor or successor of target node, we only have to point parent node of target node to the in-order predecessor or successor of the target node which will take constant amount of time.

In **best** case, cost involved will be **O(1)**, if both child of target node is leaf node, since in that case,

Left node -> in-order predecessor

Right node -> in-order successor

Note:
Even if one child is not leaf node, then we cannot consider it as best case since, wether we go for searching in-order successor or predecessor is implementation dependent.

In **worst** case, both child of target node is skewed tree, hence, **O(n)**.

Now if you see,

For factor 1, best case : O(log n)

For factor 2, best case : O(1)

Overall : O(log n) + O(1) = **O(log n)**

For factor 1, worst case : O(n)

For factor 2, worst case : O(n)

Overall : O(n) + O(n) = **O(n)**